# Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

For this query, I'm trying to average the price of all orders for a given restaurant. It works perfectly fine for the sum:

```
SELECT r.restaurantName, SUM(m.price) AS 'totalPrice w/o Tax', SUM(m.price *1.10) AS 'totalPrice w/ Tax'
FROM Restaurant r
INNER JOIN MenuItem m
ON m.restaurantNo = r.restaurantID
INNER JOIN FoodOrder f
ON m.itemNo = f.itemNo
WHERE r.restaurantName = "Eureka Pizza";
```

But when I try to average that I get an error:

```
SELECT r.restaurantName, SUM(m.price) AS 'totalPrice w/o Tax', SUM(m.price *1.10) AS 'totalPrice w/ Tax', AVG(SUM(m.price)) AS 'avg base price'
FROM Restaurant r
INNER JOIN MenuItem m
ON m.restaurantNo = r.restaurantID
INNER JOIN FoodOrder f
ON m.itemNo = f.itemNo
WHERE r.restaurantName = "Eureka Pizza";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `AVG(m.price)` in your select list.

Comment: Oh ok. So it does a SUM itself?

Comment: Yup. Try it and see...  Think of it a bit like MS Excel. If you want the average of a column, you just use the average function; you don't need to sum it first.

Comment: I tried it, it works perfectly.

Comment: That makes sense. I just assumed that I needed to nest them.

Comment: No. There are a whole bunch of "aggregate" functions like this :)  Of course, you *could* do it yourself - then it would be "sum(price) / count(*)" - but there is generally no need :)